# External Pascal in Inno script which gives Unknown Preprocessor directive

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to use the Synopse JSON library in Inno Setup. I am getting an unknown preprocessor directive.

[image]

Obviously Inno Setup uses a limited form of Pascal which doesn't include things that Synopse is using. My question is, is there a way to compile the Synopse library or otherwise transform the file so that I can still call it as an external library? I don't want to go in and mess with the Synopse code-I think the code its complaining about is fairly crucial, anyways.

Minimal example which generates error (script is in same dir as a folder called lib which contains the *.pas):

```
#define MyAppName "Minimal"
#define MyAppVersion "2.0"


[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)

AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppVerName={#MyAppName}


[Code]
#include "lib\SynCrossPlatformJSON.pas"
```

Comment: That message sounds more like an problem in your innosetup file. Could you post it?

Comment: You cannot use random Pascal code in Inno Setup. The Pascal Script is too limited. In particular, you cannot define your own classes.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl. I'm aware. I'm asking how I can take this .pas file to a form more palatable to inno setup.

Comment: @MarcoRebsamen Minimal example added, same error.

Comment: The Synopse code uses classes and pointers - Inno Setup Pascal Script does not support classes nor pointers -  You *don't want to go in and mess with the Synopse code* => **Do not use Synopse code**

Comment: Can't I compile the .pas to a .dll?

Comment: Sure, but you would have to export a function for every method you use from the library. Why don't you use existing JSON libraries for Inno Setup?

Comment: I apparently zoned out when looking at koldev's github. I'll use that. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I don't think I have enough rep, I have flagged it as dup though.